# Ubuntu Server Install for Plex - not using HDD just small NVME

Tags: server, permissions, mount, hard-drive, plex

On an unused machine that was formally a windows pc I have installed Ubunutu Server and then installed plex. This, through a process of trial and error, is working. I had a number of media files on external drive and have mounted that and plex is worked. I had other files on a mac and have been able to copy them accross. I have learnt how to use (in a basic sense) Powershell, SSH, Cyberduck, scp, chown, chmod, etc.

However, the last piece of this puzzle has been getting the bulk of my files on a hdd in the machine and not the small nvme that the server installed into. The nvme became full. Deleted some files to address that.  As far as I can tell the HDD is there and things like fdisk -l show it. I have tried to mount it to a new folder in my /media folder which is also where my external usb drive is currently mounted (and plex sees). But no luck and I am not sure if that is what I am supposed to do. It is there as /dev/sda but when I try to mount that to a directory it doesnt like the idea. The mount command says its already mounted but I cant tell where or even if that mount actually worked and the media directory is fine for more files.

Any guidance would be gratefully received.

Comment: Edit your question to show us the complete output of `df -h` while everything that you want mounted seems to be mounted.

Answer (score 0):

If Plex can see the additional drive but cannot do anything with it, then the issue may be permissions. [Based on this article](https://forums.plex.tv/t/using-ext-ntfs-or-other-format-drives-internal-or-external-on-linux/198544), you will need to do the following:

1. Switch to the super user:

   ```
   sudo su
   ```
2. Change the default directory permissions to `755`:

   ```
   find /usb/media3 -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
   ```
3. Change the default file permissions to `644`:

   ```
   find /usb/media3 -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
   ```
4. Open PMS and add the directories to the appropriate sections
5. Manually invoke a Library update

---

If you're not sure where the external device is mounted to, you can find with with `df -h`:

```
$ df -h
Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev             3927124         0   3927124   0% /dev
tmpfs             791108      3172    787936   1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p2 458726552 235684072 199670756  55% /
tmpfs            3955540        24   3955516   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120         4      5116   1% /run/lock
tmpfs            3955540         0   3955540   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1      491207920 138964460 327221748  30% /media/usb0
/dev/nvme0n1p1    997456     10264    987192   2% /boot/efi
tmpfs             791108        44    791064   1% /run/user/1000
```

For the sake of this example, I can see a storage device is mounted to `/media/usb0`, and that's where I will be able to access the data and copy new files to.

If you would like something a little easier to read, try `lsblk`:

```
$ lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda           8:0    0   477G  0 disk 
└─sda1        8:1    0   477G  0 part /media/usb0
mmcblk0     179:0    0  29.7G  0 disk 
└─mmcblk0p1 179:1    0  29.7G  0 part 
nvme0n1     259:0    0   477G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0   976M  0 part /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0 445.5G  0 part /
└─nvme0n1p3 259:3    0  30.5G  0 part [SWAP]
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks. This shows I am not really sure what I am doing because I am not asking the questions properly. Oddly, I got the external USB drive to mount after plex installed and it works. All the media on that is available. 

The problem arose when I tried to transfer files, over ssh (via windows powershell) or even Cyberduck, and this promptly filled up the nvme drive and the 1TB hard drive is sitting there gloriously empty. I tried to mount the drive to the media directory and when that didnt appear work I tried mounting the drive to a newly created directory. Again, didnt appear to work.

Comment: I say didnt appear to work as I now get messages saying the drive is mounted but I dont know where.

Comment: Updated the answer to include some methods to find your data 